# how to combine two excel tables based on a condition

Tags: microsoft-excel

We're trialling Campayn, a Mailchimp alternative, and when you download one of your contact lists from Campayn, it doesn't include the status of the contact (subscribed, unsubscribed, bounced).

We have to create a segment, create a filter for the segment (status=unsubscribed), and download the segment.

I now want to mark my master spreadsheet of contacts with the people who are unsubscribed.

In my master Excel spreadsheet, I have:

```
email, company, name
```

In my unsubscribed segment spreadsheet, I also have:

```
email, company, name
```

How do I add the word `unsubscribed` to a 4th column of the master spreadsheet for every contact in the unsubscribed segment spreadsheet?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Add a column in which concatenates all 3 column values for each row in both tables. Use VLOOKUP by this column.

Comment: One way to to use vlookup.  Create a key on both sheets by concattenating the three fields. (say data in in rows A,B and C, then insert a field before A with contents B2&C2&D2. Do that in both. then vlookup( A2, !othjersheet:table, 1,0). If found then it is in the list. Combine iwth iferror blank else "unsubscibed").

Comment: Wow. within 8 seconds of each other. :)

Comment: @Hennes Usually I recommend to split the values in concatenation with any symbol which cannot occur in cell's data ('aaa' & 'bbb' == 'aa' & 'abbb'). For these purposes I usually use something like `B2&CHAR(1)&C2&CHAR(1)&D2`. Of course, in author's case it is over...

Comment: Aye. One can improve. And one sheet does not actually need a key since you can concattenate in the vllokup formula itself. But most of the time I go for the simplest and most maintainable solution which works for the task.

Comment: You should give a specific example...!! For example with a screen shot (you don't have to use "real" data)

Answer (score 1):

Assume the master table is in 'Sheet1' with header in A1:C1.

Assume the slave table is in 'Sheet2' with header in A1:C1.

Fill 'Sheet1'D2 with formula

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B,B2,Sheet2!C:C,C2)
```

and drag it down over whole data. If a row is not present on Sheet2 you will see 0 else you will see the amount of coincident rows (typically 1).

If you want to see the 'unsubscribed' word, you may use

```
=IF(0=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B,B2,Sheet2!C:C,C2),"","unsubscribed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming two tabs:

[image: sheet or tab 1]

and

[image: Sheet or tab 2]

Key used to match identical pairs: `=B2&C2&D2`

Formula used: `=VLOOKUP(A2, Unsubscribed!$A$2:$D$2, 1, 0)`
- look for this key (first field)
- in that table (notice the $values to make it absolute
- return the first field (I do not care what is returned, just error or not)
- 0/false be precise. No fuzzy mismatching)

This work, but can be improved.

E.g. `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4, Unsubscribed!$A$2:$D$2, 1, 0),"")` would hide all the errors.

And if you add the word unsubscibed behind each email on the second tab you could do a vlookup on field 5.  The formula would then be `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4, Unsubscribed!$A$2:$E$2, 5, 0),"")`  Notice that the lookup table is now 5 fields wide (A till E, and that we return the 5th value).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a matrix formula. That's how it would look like for the second row in your table (I assume you use a headline in the first row, and the forth column is column D):

Cell "D2" will contain the following formula:

```
{=IF(SUM(IF(A2=Unsubscribed!A:A;1;0))>=1;"unsubscribed";"")}
```

You enter an Matrix Formula by using Ctrl+Shift+Enter (instead of just Enter), this will create the "{}" around the formula. For the next row A2 will change to A3 etc. (just use copy and paste, and Excel will do it for you).

If an email address is contained in the unsubscribe tabele and your master tabele it will show `unsubscribed` in the forth column, if it's only in you're master table it will show nothing.

Here's the explanation for the variables I used in the formula:

- `A2`: Cell containing the email address (in the master table)
- `A:A`: Column containing the email address (in the subscribe table)
- `Unsubscribed`: Name of the "subscribe table"

Comment: Matrix formulas are very expensive on a "big data".

Comment: @Akina Thanks, haven't considered that, since there is no further information on the number of data sets. Just wanted to give an alternative solution. I don't have exact figures, how much more "expensive" are they (for example in regards to Countif and Vlookup)?

Comment: it is not documented, of course... In practice I avoid of using them when data array contains more than 1k records. You may generate a random data set of 10 or 100k records and compare if it is interesting for you.

Comment: @Akina just tested it, the problem is using A:A in the matrix formular. If you determine the "last row" first, it works fine (even with 100k). My first guess would be the "CountIfs" algorithm ignores empty cells, the matrix formula doesn't but I didn't do a confirming test yet.